# Find the infimum of the set $\{x+\frac 1x\}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I am pretty new to the website, so I apologize in advance if I ask my question incorrectly.

I am trying to find the infimum of the Set
$$A=\left\{x+\frac{1}{x} \text{ for all }x \in \mathbb N\right\}.$$

Here's how I started: Using the definition of infimum, there is a $u$ in the set $A$ such that $u<x+\frac{1}{x}$.

From the Archimedean property, $\epsilon>0$ implies $\frac{1}{\epsilon}>0$.

I am not sure how to continue. Any advice?

Comment: @trivialmathisdifficult no, I assume that N starts with 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use AM-GM: $$n + \frac{1}{n} \ge 2\sqrt{1} = 2.$$

Comment: This proves that $2$ is a lower bound, not that it's the infimum.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for any epsilon arguments or fancy inequalities here. One can simply observe that for all $n \in \mathbb N$,
$$n + \frac{1}{n} > n.$$
Therefore for $n \geq 2$, we have
$$n + \frac{1}{n} > 2.$$
On the other hand, if $n=1$, we have
$$n + \frac{1}{n} = 2.$$
Therefore the sequence has a minimum of $2$ which occurs at $n=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that the sequence $(a)_n = \{n + \frac{1}{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is strictly increasing, and that $2 = 1 + \frac{1}{1} \in (a)_n$ is the first element in the sequence, thus a lower bound for it, by our previous comment. Indeed, $2$ is the *greatest* lower bound for $(a)_n -$ if $L$ is a greater lower bound, then $L \not< 2$.